# Problems with setting HTTP Cookie

Tags: http, cookies

I'm Base64-encoding a JSON string for a cookie.
Pasted below is the response header from the server.
When I go to the resources >> cookies tab in the Chrome Dev Console I'm not seeing the cookie. Is there something wrong with this response header?

```
Set-Cookie:cookie_vals=eyJjb29raWVCdW5kbGVLZXlOYW1lIjpbeyJLZXkiOiJ0ZXN0aW5nX2ludCIsIlZhbHVlIjoiNSIsIkV4cGlyYXRpb25NaWxsaXMiOjEzOTg3MjE3NTY0ODUsIlJlbmV3T25BY2Nlc3MiOmZhbHNlfV19; domain=localhost; expires=Tue, 28-Apr-2015 21:48:13 GMT; path=/
```

Comment: The cookie has a `domain=localhost` attribute. Are you communicating with a webserver running on your local machine using a `http(s)://localhost` URL?

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for answering this. Yes, you were correct it ended up being an issue with setting local-host for the domain.

It's a problem with IIS express...and apparently you have to hack it to have it serve requests from 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. I got it working now though...thanks for the help really appreciate it